# Taylor Expansion/Series to Prove Modified Newton's methods convergence

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, newton-raphson

Let r be a root of order 3 $f(r)=f'(r)=f''(r)=0, f'''(r)\ne0$ and let en=xn-r, show that $$e_{n+1}=\dfrac{2}{3}e_n$$ Also, show that in case of multiplicity of 2, the modified newtons method $$x_{n+1}=x{n}-2f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$$ converges quadratically to the root.

I  know how to prove that m-1/m convergence rate for m multiplicity as follows: 
Let $r$ be a root of multiplicity $m$. Then one can extract $m$ linear factors $(x-r)$ from $f$, so that $f(x)=(x-r)^mg(x)$, $g(r)\ne 0$, $g$ at least differentiable. Then $$f'(x)=m(x-r)^{m-1}g(x)+(x-r)^mg'(x)$$ and the Newton step gives
$$
x_{n+1}-r=x_n-r-\frac{(x_n-r)^mg(x_n)}{m(x_n-r)^{m-1}g(x_n)+(x_n-r)^mg'(x_n)}
\\~\\
=\frac{(m-1)g(x_n)+(x_n-r)g'(x_n)}{mg(x_n)+(x_n-r)g'(x_n)}(x_n-r)
$$
which implies
\begin{align}
e_{n+1}
&=\frac{(m-1)g(r)+e_ng'(r)+O(e_n^2)}{mg(r)+e_ng'(r)+O(e_n^2)}e_n
\\[1em]
&=\frac{m-1}{m}e_n+\frac{g'(r)}{mg(r)}e_n^2+O(e_n^3)
\end{align}

However, is there any easier way to show this? question asks me to use f(xn) and f'(xn) at r taylor expansions. I am completely confused. For the second part of the question, it asks me to use f(r+en) and f'(r+en) to prove it. All I got was $f(r+en)=f(xn)=f(r)+f'(r)*en+f''(r)/2*en^2$ then take derivative of that to get f'(xn) and plug into the modifed method but with nothing to show after.Please explain if you can thanks.

Comment: Quoted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2614429/115115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, you only need to apply the Taylor expansion also to the derivative,
$$
f'(r+e_n)=f'(r)+f''(r)e_n+\frac12f'''(r)e_n^2+...
$$
You need to use a degree of the Taylor expansion that includes at least one non-zero term.

Then insert both into the Newton step formula and apply division rules for Taylor series.

Comment: but I am left with some en*f''(x) term i just assume it to be O(en)?

Comment: Yes if you want to compute the constant for $e_n\to 0$. It may also be a hint of a calculation error. What is $x$? If $f''(r)=0$ then $f''(x_n)=f'''(r)e_n+f^{(4)}(r)e_n^2+...$ so that your term is $O(e_n^2)$.

Comment: got it also out of curiisoity is newtons method derived from first three instead of the usual two terms the halley method? so thehalley method is essntially newton?

Comment: Yes. Depending on how you use these three terms you get the original (with square roots) or current Halley's method or Laguerre's method.